# How to connect with Ontology?

Tags: web, jena, semantic-web, ontology

I'm working on a semantic news website.

I have a news data and  I want to link it with any news ontology like BBC news ontology or "Rnews" ontology.

Is there is a way to make this?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two kinds of connections between ontologies.

**Import :** With import, you import all the entities of an ontology in another. Importing all statements of an ontology is, in my experience, important when you need to implement many resources relative to the upper-ontology (Graph browsing, structure modification, ...).

**Prefixes :** On the other hand, the simple use of prefixes can solve many problems without weighing an application:

```
xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/#"
```

With prefixes you are thus able to specify that a resource is part of an ontology in a lighter and simplier way. For example with the previous statement :

`foaf:Person` is actually `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/#Person`.